# Is it possible to auto bootstrap all registered modules?

Tags: phalcon

I have structure for multimodule app, but can't understand how I can register some routes from Module.php and fire event from one module and listen for it in another. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some php frameworks register all modules before routing. For example, Zend Framework will loop through every registered module and load its bootstrap information. It will then parse the route and execute the targeted controller. The benefit is that you can do hierarchical mvc calls between modules. The drawback is you have a lot of overhead if you aren't planning on doing anything with all of those modules you bootstrapped.

To streamline the bootstrap process and load more quickly, Phalcon's framework determines the route before loading any files in the registered modules. It does not load the module.php file in each module, but instead only loads the module.php file that sits in the path of the route that will be executed. The benefit here is speed. The drawback is in trying to do hierarchical mvc across modules. At this point, phalcon has only bootstrapped the routed module, so is agnostic of any other modules.

Essentially, this means that you can only do hmvc requests within the current module. Likewise, the dispatcher in phalcon can only redirect to controllers and actions within the same module. If you need to go to another module, you can do a 301 redirect using the response->redirect action. Of course, this will generate an entirely new http request, so will not fit the hmvc paradigm.

One way to expand this functionality is to register a set of common namespaces that sit outside the modules. You can load these namespaces during the initial boot sequence started from the index.php file:

```
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();
$loader->registerNamespaces(
    array(
        'Common\Controllers'        => COMMON_PATH  . '/controllers/' ,
        'Common\Forms'              => COMMON_PATH  . '/forms/' ,
        'Common\Models'             => COMMON_PATH  . '/models/' ,
        'Common\Models\ViewHelpers' => COMMON_PATH  . '/models/ViewHelpers/' ,
        'Common\Plugins'            => COMMON_PATH  . '/plugins/' ,
    )
);
// each module will register its own namespace separately
$loader->register();
return $loader;
```

In each module's Module.php bootstrap file, you will add the additional namespaces for your given module:

```
/**
 * Register a specific autoloader for the module
 */
public function registerAutoloaders(){
    $loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();
    $loader->registerNamespaces(
        array(
            $this->_module_name . '\Controllers' => __DIR__ . '/controllers/' ,
            $this->_module_name . '\Models'      => __DIR__ . '/models/' ,
            $this->_module_name . '\Forms'       => __DIR__ . '/forms/' ,
        )
    );
    $loader->register();
}
```

Now you have namespace access to call classes in the common namespace as well as namespace access to classes in the current module's namespace:

```
$common_model = new \Common\Models\MyModel();
$module_model = new \CurrentModuleName\Models\MyModel();
```